# How to get internet explorer URL in ActiveX Control

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, activex

For some reasons from my client, I have to build an ActiveX Control for IE browser. I know the technology is old and not safe, so I decided to implement a simple security scheme where I determine the url in which the control is hosted. If the url comes from our domain, I enabled its functionality. Now how to get based ie URL in ActiveX? I have used C#.
I want to get url of web like the post [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/181678/how-to-retrieve-the-url-of-a-web-page-from-an-activex-control) but for C#.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ProTip: In general don't invent security measures unless you're a
>   cryptographer.

What you're looking for is [Per-Site ActiveX Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433050(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN.

This IS a bad idea, ActiveX is so old and even Edge doesn't even support ActiveX. Plus its dangerous to use IE8 *unless its disconnected from the internet*. You need to set your clients expectations they're asking you to build a insecure obsolete technology.

Comment: Hi, tks for answer! But i want to get url of web like the post here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/181678/how-to-retrieve-the-url-of-a-web-page-from-an-activex-control but for C#

Comment: You should have included that link in your question.